# Let $E$ be a normed space and $b\in E$. Then $d(b, \overline{X}) = d(b,X)$.

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

$d$ is the distance between a point and a set:

$d(b,X) =  \underset{x\in X}{\inf}\{\|b-x\| \} $

and

$X = B(a;r) = \{\|a-x\|<r: x \in E\}$, $ \overline{X} =  B[a;r] = \{\|a-x\| \leq r: x \in E\}$

**My attempt:**

Since $X\subset \overline{X} $, we have $d(b,\overline{X} ) \leq d(b,X)$.

Now I'd like to prove that $d(b, X) \leq d(b,\overline{X})$.

If I prove that $d(b, X) \leq \|b-x\|$ ,$\forall x\in \overline{X} $ it's done.

Now let $x\in \overline{X}$.

If $\|a-x\| < r$ then $x \in X$ and thus $d(b, X) \leq \|b-x\|$.

I'm having trouble with $\|a-x\| = r$.

How can I finish this argument?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the definition of infimum, there exists a sequence of points $(\overline{x}_n)_n$ in $\overline{X}$ such that $\|b-\overline{x}_n\| \to d(b,\overline{X})$ monotonically. By the definition of $\overline{X}$, for each $\overline{x}_n$ there exists some $x_n \in X$ such that $\|\overline{x}_n-x_n\| < 1/n$. Then by the triangle inequality,
$$0 \le \|b-x_n\|-d(b,\overline{X}) \le \|b-\overline{x}_n\| - d(b,\overline{X}) + \|\overline{x}_n-x_n\| \to 0.$$

Since we have produced a sequence $(x_n)_n$ of points in $X$ such that $\|b-x_n\| \to d(b,\overline{X})$, we must have $d(b,\overline{X}) \ge d(b,X)$.